# Can ranges overlap in ReservedPorts?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, tcpip, windows-registry, windows

The value ReservedPorts in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters contains a list of port ranges to reserve so the system won't assign them to programs dynamically.

Will the value be understood if it contains overlapping ranges?

```
4000-5000
4500-5500
6000-7000
```

I am trying to add ports to the list of reserved ports during an installation and am wondering whether I can just add my new range or whether I have to expand the existing ranges and see if my range overlaps with one of them and then extend the overlapped range instead of just adding my new range.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out Windows Server 2008 does not support the ReservedPorts registry value:

> This issue occurs because Windows Server 2008 and Windows Server 2008
>   R2 do not support the ReservedPorts registry key.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2665809

Comment: Note that the KB article you've referenced links to a hotfix re-adding this functionality and exposing an interface to exclude ports via `netsh`.

Comment: See this [StackOverflow answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37662082/2227908) for more complete instructions on using `netsh` to exclude ports from the dynamic port range in Server 2008+.